# How to set up cookies on flutter web platform?

Tags: flutter, cookies, mobile, setcookie

I have a very strange issue and I don't know how to solve it.
I figured out that my web app doesn't set cookies. I found that I need to use a Browser adapter in dio

> dio.httpClientAdapter = BrowserHttpClientAdapter(withCredentials: true);

And it is worked for me, but when I tried to run my app on iOS it is failed because BrowserHttpClientAdapter uses the library dart:html and it isn't available on mobile platforms.

> Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
> I guessed that I could create some condition import, but it didn't work.

Maybe someone has a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this problem. This article helped a lot to me:
[Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-web-node-js-cors-and-cookies-f5db8d6de882)
But in the end, I had dio, but not HTTP and I needed to configure of http adapter. It can be implemented in two ways:

```
1. _dio.httpClientAdapter = BrowserHttpClientAdapter(withCredentials: true);

2. dio.options.extra['withCredentials'] = true;
```

But be careful coz the first way works only with a web platform, BrowserHttpClientAdapter uses dart:hrml library that doesn't support mobile platforms. So I need my app to work on all OS and I use the second one and it works for me.